# Notification head's up and sound not working in android O and hinger

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have been trying to get sound and (heads up/pop up) on my notification but nothing is working I read a lot of questions on SO related to this issue and even implement most of them but nothing is working. The only thing which is working with the notification tell yet is its vibration.

**Here is my notification channel (in app class)**

**Im trying to get sound and heads up on channel2**

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOR_SERVICE,
                    utilityClass.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_FIRST, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);

            NotificationChannel channel2 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOR_REMINDER,
                    utilityClass.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_SECOND, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            channel2.enableVibration(true);
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                    .build();
            channel2.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI,audioAttributes);
            channel2.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{300, 300, 300});

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel2);
        }
    }
```

**And here I'm creating notification**

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MarkNotificationService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), (int) currentTime, intent, 0);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_FOR_REMINDER)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_bookmark_border_24, "Reminder", pendingIntent).build();
    
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify((int) currentTime, notification);
```

***EDIT: If I manually give floating notification permission in system app sitting then it works fine (heads up)***

Answer (score 0):

Add these permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

2.Add build method

```
 public NotificationCompat.Builder createBuilder(Context context
            , NotificationManagerCompat manager) {
        String channelId = context.getPackageName();
        NotificationCompat.Builder notBuilder = new NotificationCompat
                .Builder(context, channelId);
        notBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        notBuilder.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3580FF"));
        notBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notBuilder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        notBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        notBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId
                    , "Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.shouldShowLights();
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.canBypassDnd();
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            channel.setDescription("Notifications");
            notBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        return notBuilder;
    }
```

3.Show notification

```
NotificationManagerCompat manager=NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = createBuilder(
                    context, manager);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setContentText(message);
            builder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_NAVIGATION);
            Intent parentIntent = new Intent(context, ActHome.class);
            parentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context
                    , NOTIFICATION_ID, parentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT |
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

4.If still doesn't work Uninstall and reinstall the app

Comment: i implemented your whole code in my app, but still its not making head up, sound, and neither vibration